# How to declare a type for a default export in Node.js

Tags: typescript

```
export const func1: Function = (): boolean => true;
```

In the above line, func1 is `Function`. If I want to use a default export like below, How to declare the default export as Function??

```
export default (): boolean => true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply un-inline the value:

```
const func1: Function = (): boolean => true;
export default func1;
```